# login solution to prevent brute force attacks

Tags: php

It would be good to get cons and pros for such solution. And also get opinion how useful the solution is to prevent attacks (does it help much).

Each username (user) has unique url to login. Here is example https://secure.freshbooks.com/loginSearch.php

I see such pros:

1. multiple users can use the same username
2. for each username hacker must use different url (the question here is: how much more difficult it is for hackers? may be it is easy to write special programm)
3. it takes much time to get urls to login (comparing with sigle login.php)
4. .... possibly there are more pros

Cons from my opinion is that for each username separate subdomain is created. May be better to use like `www.page.com/user/`. Also if for example 100000 users want the same username. What would be better solution to name the url `..../username`?

And question is how to code it? username from mysql; add the username to url... then?

Would be good to know your opinions.

Hope this is not deemed as offtopic or repost of question...

Comment: It's not a separate subdomain, neither a separate file. It is a `GET` parameter passed in the query. Then `Apache` rewrites the query how you like to see it in your browser.

Comment: With your advice I understand such process:1) user chooses business name; 2) check if such business name exists in mysql, if yes, add something to the business name and record in mysql; 3) base url is /login.php Get business name from mysql and with variable add to /login.php like /login.php?u='.$businessname 4) with htaccess change (rewrite url)

Answer (score 1):

Hackers using a brute force attack will already know the username they are trying to hack in to. They will just be brute forcing the password, so this isn't really an effective defence.

A better way might be to have a limit on login attempts, but make it something really high that no normal user should ever see, like 100.

Comment: I have no much knowledge. But if only one login page for all users and many requests for the page, then it may freeze (slow down)?

Comment: And regarding hackers already know username. I mean hacker try one username, get banned for 5-10 minutes (because of failed attempts). Then hacker simply takes next username in the same login page. In case of multiple login pages hacker must go to other url... And the question is: how hackers can get to know usernames. They may simply guess?

Comment: Having 10,000 requests for the same page, and 10,000 requests for 10,000 separate (but identical) pages is the same thing, you won't be saving resources by having separate pages.

Secondly allowing people to have the same username increases the chances of being hacked, the chances of success for the hacker increase with each user that shares a username. Thirdly, if you have any sort of area within the site that exposes a username, like a forum, they will get it from there (even if they have to make a fake account), if not then that is a small protection.

Comment: hmmm... ok, thanks for opinions. May I ask for explanation how it increases chances of being hacked? From my opinion validation may be like this: if url is for certain username but other username and even correct password is typed, then fail.

Comment: Imagine that the number of possible passwords for a user on your site is `pwnum`. Every time you guess a password, your chance of success is `1/pwnum`. If you have 2 users with the same username, the chance doubles to `2/pwnum`, if you have 3 users it becomes `3/pwnum`, and grows like that with every extra user.

Comment: sorry, can not catch your thoughts.... Unique url for each user (username). Enter url, type correct username, type incorrect password... pwnum variations of password. Second user with the same username. But url is not the same. Usernames may be the same, but urls are not. So at first need to guess (know) url, then need to guess (know) username (only one correct username for each url), then pwnum variations for password... May be I do not understand something

Comment: Oh ok, I thought each username would have the same URL so you could have several users using the same URL. How are you generating the URL for each user?

Answer (score 1):

I made a class that takes care of brute force attack protection in PHP.

https://github.com/ejfrancis/BruteForceBlocker

it logs all failed logins site-wide in a db table, and if the number of failed logins in the last 10 minutes (or whatever time frame you choose) is over a set limit, it enforces a time delay and/or a captcha requirement before logging in again.

example:

> //build throttle settings array. (# recent failed logins => response).
>
> $throttle_settings = [
>
> ```
>     50 => 2,            //delay in seconds
>     150 => 4,           //delay in seconds
>     300 => 'captcha'    //captcha
> ```
>
> ];
>
> $BFBresponse = BruteForceBlocker::getLoginStatus($throttle_settings);
>
> //$throttle_settings is an optional parameter. if it's not included,the default settings array in BruteForceBlocker.php will be used
>
> switch ($BFBresponse['status']){
>
> ```
> case 'safe':
>     //safe to login
>     break;
> case 'error':
>     //error occured. get message
>     $error_message = $BFBresponse['message'];
>     break;
> case 'delay':
>     //time delay required before next login
>     $remaining_delay_in_seconds = $BFBresponse['message'];
>     break;
> case 'captcha':
>     //captcha required
>     break;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this pseudocode?

```
    $searchresult = mysql_query($searchquery) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($searchresult) == 0) {
       echo "no rows found";  (DIE)
    }

    else {
    $attemptTime = "SELECT TimeStamp FROM UserLogTable WHERE `UserName` LIKE '%{$userName}%'";
    $attempts = "SELECT attempts FROM UserLogTable WHERE `UserName` LIKE '%{$userName}%'";

    if ( $attemptTime < time()-10 ){  // Reset attempt after 10 min
attempts = 0;
   "INSERT "$attempts" INTO attempts / UserLogTable WHERE `UserName` LIKE '%{$userName}%'";
}

     if (attempts > 3) { 
     echo "Too many attempts you must wait 5 minutes")

      else { 
       Run database check on password 
          if ( password failed ) {
          $attempts++
          "INSERT "$attempts" INTO attempts / UserLogTable WHERE `UserName` LIKE '%{$userName}%'";
          DIE("Bad Login")
          else { 
           $attempts = 0
          "INSERT "$attempts" INTO attempts / UserLogTable WHERE `UserName` LIKE '%{$userName}%'"; // reset attempts
           login user 
           }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought ... why not ban attacking IP after x-number of unsuccessful attacks? Alternately (and probably easier), require human verification (such as Captcha) to disrupt scripted attacks. I'm not smart on the actual coding (although I have used the new HTML5 drag and drop as an alternative to Captcha), but the general idea should work, yes?